# External HDD Disconnects and Reconnects repeatedly

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3

Please note this is not a power issue, My A-DATA HD710's USB 3.0 connector (The socket inside the external HDD) has become loose (somehow, I don't know what happened), now the HDD keeps disconnecting and reconnecting randomly (every 5-20 seconds or so).
Have any of you ever faced this problem? if so do you know any fixes?

Comment: A mobile phone repair shop should be able to resolder / change that connector, if it's physically damaged

Comment: Are you sure? The socket doesn't seem to be easily replaceable

Comment: The shop decides if they can do it or not

Answer (score 0):

This is defiantly a power issue in USB 3 only. not for the HD but for the USB 3 port. usb3.0 has some power saving mode that lets the hard drive power down. there is so many solution to avoid that behavior.

1. check the port of your USB 3 and if it is a hub or an extended cable remove it or replace the cable with another one.
2. check the looseness of the USB 3 port.
3. update your USB 3 driver from the site of your motherboard.
4. uninstall the USB driver of the Case and reinstall it again.
5. turn off windows indexing.
6. disable USB saving power option in "Change plan setting".
7. reconnect your drive to a regular USB 2 port.

Comment: I am aware of that solution, I googled before asking. As I stated in the answer this is NOT a power issue, I asked my question very clearly none of those suggestions helps I already know for sure that the HDD's usb 3.0 port is loose and is the cause of this problem

Comment: some of my solutions are not power related.

Comment: Yes and thank you very much for the answer but I've already tried all of those